# Converting XML to JSON in JAVA

Tags: java, json, xml

I'm trying to convert an `XML` `String` to a `JSON` object using [this](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformat-xml/wiki) `jackson` library.
This works great for `XML` strings where each elements occurs only once.

But for XML where a certain element repeats itself more than once, the `JSON` object I receive contains it only once.

For example:

XML:

```
<a>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
    <b></b>
</a>
```

And the JSON:

```
{"a":{"b":""}}
```

Where I need it to be:

```
{"a": [{"b":"","b":"","b":""}]}
```

How can I achieve that? 
EDIT:

I need the `JSON` to be like this:

```
{"a":[{"b":""},{"b":""},{"b":""}]}
```

Or as @exoddus said in the comments:

```
{ "a": { "b": [ "value1", "value2" ] } }
```

Would be fine as well.

i.e convert multiple occurrences of an element to an `array`.

My goal is to implement a`SOAP` service with a `REST` web service. It is working just as I expected except for this issue with arrays and multiple occurrences.

Comment: Your required output `{"a": [{"b":"","b":"","b":""}]}` is not valid JSON. A JSON object must not contain duplicate keys.

Comment: Regarding XML, you should be more precise on your wording: Your `<b>`'s are not attributes, but elements!

Comment: you should produce a JSON like that: { "a": [ "b", "b", "b" ] }

Comment: @exoddus And what about the content of the  `b` elements (if any)?

Comment: @Tichodroma <a><b>val1</b><b>val2</b></a> ==> { "a": { "b": [ "value1", "value2" ] } }